# Spring Log4j2 xml file location

Tags: spring, log4j2

using Spring 2.0.5 with Log4j2
Have found works as expected if I place the file log4j2.xml in the resources folder.
However, have found the log4j2 option of monitorInterval="60" to be super useful as if some production issue can increase logging on some class without a restart. However if log4j2.xml is embedded in the jar of course it cannot be modified. so far the best I have been able to do is use 2 copies of log4j2.xml one in the resources and the other in the folder running the jar from.

I can then run:

```
java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.xml -jar myapp.jar
```

it seems to work the same if started from the maven spring-boot plugin or from Eclipse. 
Have tried a number of things such as setting the classpath, the absolute file name etc. but no luck

My question is how can I remove the log4j2.xml file from the resources folder and only specify it on the command line when starting spring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely clear on your question but I can provide the following information which I hope addresses it:

1. Log4j 2.12.0 added support for Spring Cloud Config and enhanced the support for Spring Boot. As of that version you can include a file named log4j2.system.properties and place any system properties you want defined there. They will be set before Log4j initializes. So you can specify the full URL to the configuration there if you want instead of the command line. You can also add the definition to a file named log4j2.component.properties.
2. The support for Spring Cloud Config allows you to place the configuration in your Spring Cloud Config server. See [Spring CLoud Config support](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-spring-cloud-config/log4j-spring-cloud-config-client/index.html) for more details.
3. Spring Boot initializes logging at least 3 times. The first is usually because the SpringApplication class declares a Logger so logging is initialized before anything else happens. The configuration for that will use "normal" log4j 2 initialization. After that Spring influences how logging initialization occurs primarily because Spring Boot sets the class path to include the jars inside BOOT-INF/lib directory inside your Spring Boot jar.

By using one of the configuration options I outlined above you can move the logging configuration outside of your application and you should not require a logging configuration in the resources directory. In fact, if you look at the [sample Spring Cloud Config Application](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/tree/master/log4j-spring-cloud-config/log4j-spring-cloud-config-samples/log4j-spring-cloud-config-sample-application) in Log4j you will see it does not include a configuration file in it.